# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'cheerio' Nodewebkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, cheerio

I am trying to develop a node webkit application and trying to use the cheerio library.
I have imported it using `var cheerio    = require("cheerio");`

However when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'cheerio'      module.js:329
```

My node_modules folder contains the cheerio folder and I have included it in my package.json file as well. I even tried installing cheerio globally and I face this error.

Comment: Is cheerio installed globally or inside your parent directory?

Comment: @Patel I have tried both. It is installed globally and in my parent directory under node_modules folder

Comment: Did you try doing `require` by giving path?

Comment: @Patel Yeah I tried giving whole path as well. Still did not work